# Does anyone know a translation into VB for the below code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

```
customers =
                (
                    from c in xDoc.Descendants("customer")
                    orderby c.Attribute("CustomerID").Value

                    select new Customer
                    {
                        ID = c.Attribute("CustomerID").Value,
                        CompanyName = c.Attribute("CompanyName").Value,
                        ContactName = c.Attribute("ContactName").Value,
                        ContactTitle = c.Attribute("ContactTitle").Value,
                        Address = c.Attribute("Address").Value,
                        City = c.Attribute("City").Value,
                        State = c.Attribute("State").Value,
                        ZIPCode = c.Attribute("ZIPCode").Value,
                        Phone = c.Attribute("Phone").Value
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

Comment: ...seriously? Is that even a question? Would you do that if some random person came to you and gave you nothing but this?

Comment: @Tomalak - you must not work in a corporate environment. I get requests like these from within my organization on a daily basis.

Comment: The .ToList() makes me cringe as much as anything else.  It's almost always a mistake.  For that matter, the OrderBy is likely pre-mature is as well.  Save anything that actually requires iterating over the results for as late as possible in your process.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Can you provide a link that discusses why? I do this from time to time. I'd like to understand why.

Comment: @Joel Etherton - There are two reason: 1. It forces your program to load all that data into memory, when it may not need to.  2. It forces your program to iterate over the results right now, when you might yet want to do further composition of the result set that could further pare down what work is needed.  In a nutshell - it has the _potential_ to be **really bad** for performance.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Maybe, but you get paid for this. Big difference. :-)

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: does it differ from new `List<myClass>(... linq query ...)` performance-wise or are they comparable? I'm a big fan of strongly typed lists, but if I'm shooting myself in the foot, it would be really cool to know that before I pull the trigger.

Comment: @Joel Etherton - also avoid using `new List<MyClass>` - use `IEnumerable<MyClass>` instead.  Think of it in terms of a stream of operations on your data as it move through your system from the database to your final presentation.  You want to stay with IEnumerable as long as possible in that stream before converting to a list or otherwise actually materializing the data.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - Well I haven't experienced performance issues, and most of my uses are small enough that I probably never will, but best practices are best practices. I like to keep it clean rather than buy into bad habits. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim customers = (From c In xDoc.Descendants("customer")Order By c.Attribute("CustomerID").Value
 Select New Customer() With { _
  .ID = c.Attribute("CustomerID").Value, _
  .CompanyName = c.Attribute("CompanyName").Value, _
  .ContactName = c.Attribute("ContactName").Value, _
  .ContactTitle = c.Attribute("ContactTitle").Value, _
  .Address = c.Attribute("Address").Value, _
  .City = c.Attribute("City").Value, _
  .State = c.Attribute("State").Value, _
  .ZIPCode = c.Attribute("ZIPCode").Value, _
  .Phone = c.Attribute("Phone").Value _
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Joel sorry for the crazy nooobness but what is Key?

Comment: @xxmrlnxx: holy crap find/replace. That was find/replace error. There is no key. I've posted a correction.